# Finding probabilities P(x) = 2 P(y)

Tags: probability

P(s) = P(r) = 0.1, P(d) = 0.35, P(x) = 2P(y).

I need to find the probability of P(x) and P(y). What I did so far is P(s)+P(r)+P(0.35) = 0.55, meaning 1-0.55 = 0.45 will have to be distributed for P(x) and P(y). I have no idea how I would find P(x) and P(y). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(x)+P(y) = 0.45$

$2P(y)+P(y) = 0.45$

$3P(y) = 0.45$, so $P(y) = 0.15$, $P(x) = 0.30$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
P(x) + P(y) &= 0.45 \\
\implies 2P(y) + P(y) &= 0.45\\
\implies 3P(y) &= 0.45 \\
\implies P(y) &= 0.15 \\
\implies P(x) &= 0.30.
\end{align*}

Comment: should it be p(x)+p(y) = 0.45?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that $s$ and $r$ were both 0.1.